# scheme - can someone explain this output to me?

Tags: linked-list, scheme, racket, fold

With these defined functions:

```
(define (foldr op z ls)
  (if (null? ls)
  z
  (op (car ls) (foldr op z (cdr ls)))))

(define (snoc x y) (cons y x))
```

and when i run this:

```
(foldr snoc '() (list 1 2 3))
```

I get this output:

```
=> (((() . 3) . 2) . 1)
```

What does this output mean? Can someone please explain it to me in detail?
I need to Draw this answer in terms of box and pointer notation in scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Racket prints cons cells as "dotted pairs" if their `cdr` isn't a list.

Examples from DrRacket:

```
> (list 1 2)
'(1 2)
> '(1 . (2 . ()))
'(1 2)
> '(1 . 2)
'(1 . 2)
> (cons 1 2)
'(1 . 2)
> (cons 1 '())
'(1)
> (cons '() 1)
'(() . 1)
```

`(foldr op z ls)` takes `ls` and replaces `nil` with `z` and `cons` with `op`.

That is, if `ls` is `(cons a (cons b (cons c nil)))`, then `(foldr op z ls)` is

```
(op a (op b (op c z)))
```

In your example, `(foldr snoc '() (list 1 2 3))` is

```
(snoc 1 (snoc 2 (snoc 3 '())))
```

Working your way outwards from the innermost `snoc`,

```
(snoc 1 (snoc 2 (cons '() 3)))

(snoc 1 (cons (cons '() 3) 2))

(cons (cons (cons '() 3) 2) 1)
```

which prints (in DrRacket) as dotted pairs

```
'(((() . 3) . 2) . 1)
```

(Drawing a diagram left as an exercise.)

Comment: It's easier to understand this if you know `(1 2 3)` is actually a simplified visualization of `(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))`